# Jenkins execute shell is escaping -- characters

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to run following command from executable shell task:

```
rhc configure-app -a TestProject20140324192518 -–deployment-type binary
```

But when I run the jenkins job, it converts the command to:

```
rhc configure-app -a TestProject20140324192518 $'-\342\200\223deployment-type' binary
```

Do I need to escape -- here ?

If I put above command in .sh, it runs just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like a hyphen - did you copy the command from somewhere?

Instead of:

```
rhc configure-app -a TestProject20140324192518 -–deployment-type binary
```

Try:

```
rhc configure-app -a TestProject20140324192518 --deployment-type binary
```

Note that the character immediately before "deployment-type" has been changed.

Comment: Yup, that is definitely not a hyphen `-`. Copy the second command line from Josh's example